# How to return all values of a column as null except one column value in LINQ?

Tags: linq

I want to return only one column value and other column values as null from database. how can i do that in LINQ? also have to make values of not nullable fields to null while retrieving

Comment: Can explain your requirement a little more clearer with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#

```
var results = from item in db.items
              select (item.col1 == value ? item.col1 : null);
```

VB.NET

```
Dim results = From item in db.items
              Select iif(item.col1 == value ? item1.col : Nothing)
```